# How to remove element from non-associative array in php

Tags: php, arrays, unset

I'm trying to remove specific element from php array with unset function. Problem is that when I var_dump array it shows all indexes (not good) but If I try to var_dump specific index PHP throws warning (good).

```
$a = [
    'unset_me',
    'leave_me',
    'whatever',
];

unset($a['unset_me']);

var_dump($a);
/**
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "unset_me"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "leave_me"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "whatever
*/
var_dump($a['unset_me']); // Undefined index: unset_me
```

Question is why php behave like this and how to remove index properly?

Comment: `unset($a[0]);` - the array has numerical indexes, there is no element with the string index `unset_me`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this with `array_search` -

```
unset($a[array_search('unset_me', $a)]);
```

If needed then add the checks like -

```
if(array_search('unset_me', $a) !== false) {
    unset($a[array_search('unset_me', $a)]);
}
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/488555)

Comment: @Steve if the checks added properly it will be all fine. You can check the update. I have already mentioned about it.  That was happening because `array_search` returning `false` and `false` considered as `0`.  :)

Comment: @Sougata: you are the best... most active person.

Answer (score 7):

One more solution:

```
$arr = array('unset_me','leave_me','whatever',);  
print_r($arr);

// remove the elements that you want  
$arr = array_diff($arr, array("unset_me"));
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: This is better than anything involving `array_search`.  Simpler, less points of failure, and less disruptive to the structure of the array.

Comment: If the arrays contain arrays or objects, this method will result in an error due to array/object to string conversion. Not a great solution for general use.

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = array('unset_me','leave_me','whatever',);  
print_r($arr);
echo '<br/>';

$key = array_search('unset_me', $arr);
if($key !== false)
unset($arr[$key]);

print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered this problem and found this solution helped:

`unset($a[array_flip($a)['unset_me']]);`

Just to explain what is going on here:

`array_flip($a)` switches the items for the key. So it would become:

```
$a = [
    'unset_me' => 0,
    'leave_me' => 1,
    'whatever' => 2,
];
```

`array_flip($a)['unset_me']` therefore resolves to being 0. So that expression is put into the original `$a` which can then be unset.

2 caveats here:

- This would only work for your basic array, if you had an array of objects or arrays, then you would need to choose one of the other solutions
- The key that you remove will be missing from the array, so in this case, there will not be an item at `0` and the array would start from `1`. If it is important to you, you can do `array_values($a)` to reset the keys.